# How can I require (in a C++20 concept) that a type T be a reference to a floating point type?

Tags: c++, reference, c++20, c++-concepts

In the C++20 concepts library, there is `std::floating_point<T>` which "is satisfied if and only if T is a floating-point type" ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/floating_point)). But I need `T` to be a *reference* to a floating-point type. What is a `requires` clause that expresses this?

Comment: Am I missing something beyond “use type traits before applying the concept”?

Comment: Just a little bit, @davis, `remove_reference_t` will drop the reference, if it's a reference, otherwise it will return the same type, so you need to use `remove_reference_t`, then `is_same_v` to check that it's ***not*** the same, and finally, `floating_point_v` to cross the finish line.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm really not versed in templates and requires clauses; could you show me what this would look like?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I’m pretty sure those are all type traits…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Davis said in the comments, just use type traits:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_floating_point_reference = 
    std::is_reference_v<T> &&
    std::floating_point<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```